# PHP: $_SESSION doesn't set

Tags: php, session

Before setting as duplicate, I've spent 4 hours on researching about my problem, but I had no luck.

I am trying to make a signup/login system for my website. The main point that doesn't seem to work is that when I am signing up on my website, the session doesn't seem to start. The reason that I can see it is because, on my navbar, I have set it to change from signup to log out. Here is the piece of code for that:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list1"><a href="GeorgeKarabassis.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="list2"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li class="list3"><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li class="list4"><a href="Blog.php">Blog</a></li>
    <li class="list4"><a href="contact_us.php">Contact</a></li>
    <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
            echo "<li><a href='#'>SIGN OUT</a></li>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<li><a onclick='signup(event)' href='#'>SIGN UP</a></li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

To make that I have created three files. One is the mane page, one is the signup file itself, code below:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "../dbh.php";

    $first = $_POST["first"];
    $last = $_POST["last"];
    $uid = $_POST["uid"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $pwd = $_POST["pwd"];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (first,last,uid,email,pwd) VALUES ('$first','$last','$uid','$email','$pwd')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
```

and the last one is the file which connects PHP to the database code below:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("XXX","XXX","XXX","XXX");

if (!$conn){
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

I believe that the session doesn't start because the main page reloads after the user hits signup on the form, but I have started the session on all of my files (except the database connection file where it's not needed). I used session start on all of my page and I placed it on the beginning of all pages with opening and closing PHP tags.

Any suggestions? I appreciate your answers and comments!

Sorry for the bad English but it's not my first language.

Comment: Please remove your DB login data. And don't use root. Especially with no password set.

Comment: @Ty221 it is for sure local tests, chill out ( about database connection )

Comment: Do you have error reporting on? Do you see any warnings, notices, errors given to you by PHP? Did you give us full content of the first file?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And an `insert` query doesn't return a result set. you can **NOT** `fetch()` from an insert. That means `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` will fail, return boolean false, and then you blindly use that false as an array - so you're assigning NULL to your session var.

Comment: @MaciejSikora Good practices should be followed even during local tests.

Comment: Hello Ty221, I can't remove the root because this is my username for my localhost server. Before attempting to create a signup system, I watched a video tutorial and it said that I have to use these parameters in mysqli_connect function. I cannot still figure out what my error is. Thank you for the comment by the way.

Comment: Ty221, the first file is quite large to post but i believe that this is the required code to be posted and I am 100% sure that the error is in between these posted codes.

Comment: @GeorGios Does this first file have `session_start()` on its very beginning?

Comment: From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php): `For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.`  The second part is relevant here, as you are trying to use the return value as if it is an object.

Comment: I believe your $result is not returning an $id, as your assuming in your code. I believe you can use SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()  for that, if the id row in your table has the primary key.

Comment: @Ty221 yes it does. All of my files have session_start() in the beginning with open/close tags.

Comment: @Marc B haha, my apologies; I know nothing about PHP and database security

Comment: @GeorGios Then I hope you take a look on some common issues before publishing your project. Security is very important. The good point to start is OWASP Top Ten :) https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (first,last,uid,email,pwd) VALUES ('$first','$last','$uid','$email','$pwd')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
```

Insert queries do **NOT** return a result set, and you can NOT `fetch()` from them. That means `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is failing, and returning a boolean FALSE. You then use that boolean false as if it was an array, and are basically doing the equivalent of

```
$_SESSION['id'] = null;
```

Note this:

```
php > $foo = false;
php > $id = $foo['id'];
php > var_dump($id);
NULL
```

You want

```
$_SESSION['id'] = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Mark B. I appreciate it. Can you please elaborate on this mysqli_insert_id($conn); please, like how it works and what is it?

Comment: However it works, thank you very much but can you explain to me what mysqli_insert_id($conn) means, please.

Comment: Seems that your answer helped me for my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

It is an error with you SQL query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (first,last,uid,email,pwd) VALUES ('$first','$last','$uid','$email','$pwd')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

The first line of the code is an `INSERT` command. The second line executes this command by sending it to the server. If query is properly processed then MySQL server doesn't return you anything, so `$result` will equal to `true`. **It wil not contain any data from the database**. So you can't fetch it, what you try to do in the third line. Need to make a separate query for data.